# Countdown for Woocommerce product on Archive / Loop page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've made a countdown to display the sale date end using the meta key `_sale_price_to` . See below the code :

```
add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_timer_two', 'sales_timer_countdown_product_two', 20 );
function sales_timer_countdown_product_two($atts) {
            extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'woocommerce_timer_two' ) ); 

    global $product;
    
         // If the product object is not defined, we get it from the product ID
    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') && get_post_type($id) === 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($id);
    }
    
    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {

    $sale_date = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price_dates_to', true );
    
    if ( ! empty( $sale_date ) ) {
        
        ?>
        <script>
            
        jQuery(function($){
        "use strict";

        $('.countdown-counter').each( function() {
        var to = $(this).attr("countdown");
        var thisis = $(this);
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var countDownDate = <?php echo $sale_date; ?> * 1000;

            // Update the count down every 1 second
            var x = setInterval(function() {
                // Get today's date and time
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                    
                // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                var distance = countDownDate - now;     
                    
                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                    
                // Output the result in an element with id="sale-end"
                var html = days + hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds;
                thisis.html(html);
                    
                // If the count down is over, write some text 
                if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                parent.css("display", "none");
            }
        }, 1000);
        thisis.removeAttr("countdown");
        });
        });
        </script>
        <!-- this is where the countdown is displayed -->
        <div class="product-countdown">
             <span class="countdown-counter" countdown="'. $html .'"></span>
        </div>;
        <?php
    }
    }
}
```

The code works on the product single page but I need it on the archive and loop page. On the archive page, all the products have the same value for the countdown. I guess it's because I can't give an attribute for each archive item.

Related posts that may help :

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725260/countdown-for-woocommerce-products)
- [Link 2](https://axlmulat.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-tutorial-how-to-add-sales-countdown-timer-in-the-product-page/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this code is working on product single page then you can add an action hook in archive/loop page using WooCommerce hooks.

example :-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'zillion_countdown_show_in_loop', 20 );
function zillion_countdown_show_in_loop()
{
    do_shortcode('[woocommerce_timer_two]');
 
}
```

EDITED

you can replace the class with product id added with it.

```
$('.countdown-counter<?php echo $product->get_id();?>')
```

replace html part also.

```
<div class="product-countdown">
    <span class="countdown-counter<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>" countdown="'. $html .'"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The result is that all products with a sale date have the same countdown. It's explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725260/countdown-for-woocommerce-products). They should have their own attribut otherwise script from `product y` will overrride script from `product x`

Comment: You can try replacing classes with product_id in jquery and html then it should run for specific product class only. i've added a example in my answer.